# solr responses to webbrowser URL but not from javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, solr

I have set up Solr and it's working because I can see the search results when I'm typing:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*
```

in the browser.

However, it doesn't work when I try to contact it through ajax-javascript/jquery.

I've tried with `$.get`, `$.post` and with the ajax-solr code:

```
var Manager;
(function ($) {

  $(function () {
    Manager = new AjaxSolr.Manager({
      solrUrl: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select'
    });
    Manager.init();
    Manager.store.addByValue('q', '*:*');
    Manager.doRequest();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

I get no response when I'm checking with firebug.

How comes?

Comment: Are you sure you included jQuery too?

Comment: yes im sure. i am doing this with php instead. it works much better than this complex jquery ajax thing=)

Comment: do you see any errors in the firebug console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the most recent version of ajax-solr, you must remove the trailing "select":

```
var Manager;
(function ($) {

  $(function () {
    Manager = new AjaxSolr.Manager({
      solrUrl: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/'
    });
    Manager.init();
    Manager.store.addByValue('q', '*:*');
    Manager.doRequest();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

This change was made as some users needed to be able to contact multiple request handlers.